# Why Logger.log does not see second argument and console.log does?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a function that takes two arguments and do things. Then I have a function that I am stuck with.
The second function should pass arguments from the `range` to the `item1()` func.
I am getting an error at the `item1` because it misses the second argument. When I tried to log passed arguments strange thing happened, because:

```
range = [[GWPA4205022, 1550.0], [CWPA8005121, 1000.0], [, ]]
```

`Logger.log(range[1][0],range[1][1]);`  logs: `CWPA8005121`

`console.log(range[1][0],range[1][1]);` logs: `CWPA8005121 1000`

What is the difference between those two? and how it can be fixed? Logging within a loop or outside brings the same resultat.

my function looks like this:

```
function callItem(){
const sheetName = "SHEET2"; 
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
const range = sheet.getRange(4, 2, sheet.getLastRow(),2).getValues(); 

Logger.log(range);
Logger.log(range[1][0],range[1][1]);
console.log(range[1][0],range[1][1]);


  for(var i = 0; i < range.length; i++){
    if(range[i][0] !== ""){
      item1(range[i][0],range[i][1]);   
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `Logger.log` takes one argument by design

I'm afraid that is just the way that Google wrote the function.

> https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/logger

#### Options

- Concatenate strings - Like Cooper showed in the other answer
- Keep on using `console.log`
- Use a [format string](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/logger#logformat,-values) `Logger.log("%s %s", range[1][0], range[1][1])`. Or `` Logger.log(`${range[1][0]} ${range[1][1]}`) ``
- You could even write your own function as a wrapper around `Logger` if you don't want to use `console.log`

```js
function myLog(...args) {
    Logger.log(args.join(", ")) // This just joins all arguments into a string separated by commas
}

let h = "hello"
let w = "world"
myLog(h, w) // "hello, world"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `Logger.log(range[1][0] + ',' + range[1][1]);`

also

`const range = sheet.getRange(4, 2, sheet.getLastRow()-3,2).getValues();`

Comment: Thanks! it started to log correctly but still called function is missing second argument

Comment: item1 is undefined